# giving a user read and write permissions to 2 different user's home directories

Tags: linux, permissions

I have 2 users in linux operating system.

user1 (home directory: /home/user1) 
and 
user2 (home directory: /home/user2)

I want a third user, user3, to be able to access to user1 and user2 home directories for both read and write. But user1 and user2 should not have any access to each other's home directories.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use groups.

Create a group xyzzy and make user3 member of it. Users 1 and 2 should not belong to that group.

Make /home/user1 and /home/user2 writable to a group xyzzy

```
chgrp xyzzy /home/user1 /home/user2;chmod 770 /home/user1 /home/user2
```

Hannu